# ¿Por qué onclick submit no envía mi variable php al dar click sobre imagen?

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, submit

Tengo una consulta, quisiera que me ayudaran, tengo 2 archivos: archivo1.php y resultado.php en el archivo1.php tengo el código inicial donde necesito hacer un submit y enviar un valor de un radio button al hacer click en una imagen, para ello me valí de javascript y ciertamente hace el submit, pero la variable php no envía nada, ¿por qué será? A continuación estan los códigos de los 2 archivos:

Archivo1.php

```
<script>
    function enviar(){
document.getElementById("form_name").submit();
    }
</script>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="resultado.php" method="post" id="form_name" name="form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="city" value="1" checked="checked">
                    <img src="imagen1.png" alt="imagen" onclick="enviar()">
                    </label>
                  </td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="city" value="2">
                    <img src="imagen2.png" alt="imagen" onclick="enviar()">
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

resultado.php

```
$res = $_POST['city'];
     echo "El valor es $res";
```

Pero al imprimir lo anterior es como que si la variable no recibiera nada. ¿Por qué será?

Answer (score 0):

Te lo mostrare de una manera sencilla...

---

**Html**

```
<input type="radio" name="city" value="1" checked="checked">
```

**JavaSript**

```
let city = document.getElementById('city');
$(function enviar() {
    $.post('resultado.php', {
        "city_envio": city,
    }, function (data) {
        console.log('procesamiento finalizado', data);
    });
})
```

**resultado.php**

```
$res = $POST['city_envio'];
echo "El valor es".$res;
```

Comment: Gracias, intentaré de esta forma Josue, solo que en la parte de ¨let city = document.getElementById('city');¨tiene que ser ¨let city = document.getElementByName('city');¨ verdad?

Comment: No me funcionó Josue, se que lo hiciste ver sencillo pero no se por qué razón no funciona, otra cosa que te iba a mencionar es que al momento de dejarlo con el código que yo tenía y dejo la propiedad checked="checked" al que le dejo esa propiedad, me envía ese valor incluso si yo selecciono el otro.

Answer (score -1):

Ok,

La logica es la siguiente: cuando haces click a cualquier elemento con `class="enviar-radio"`, debe correr logica de buscar al elemente anterior que sea un input, y que le ponga la propiedad de checked. Y despues mandar el formulario.

Usando JQuery puedes hacer esto

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="resultado.php" method="post" id="form_name" name="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <!-- El Input siempre tiene que estar antes de la imagen. Y la imagen que va a mandar la informacion tiene que tener la clase: enviar-radio -->
                            <input type="radio" name="city" value="1">
                            <img src="imagen1.png" alt="imagen" class="enviar-radio">
                        </label> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="city" value="2">
                            <img src="imagen2.png" alt="imagen" class="enviar-radio">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.enviar-radio').on('click', function(){
                // Find Previous and Set to Check
                $(this).prev('input').prop('checked', 'checked');

                // Send Form
                enviar();
            })
        });

        function enviar(){
            document.getElementById("form_name").submit();
        }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Me aparece esto: Array ( )

Comment: Ok, y estas seguro 100% que estas llegando al resultado.php??  Crea un button: <button type="submit">Submit"</button> . Hasle click, debe mandar el formulario a resultado.php

Comment: ahhh ya se cual es el error.. Tu estas usando tu images como la seleccion verdad?  Segun tu codigo la sequencia de intaracion es:  Hacer click al radio y despues apretar la imagen. Si no le haces click al radio, no hay seleccion.

Comment: si uso un boton de submit en vez de como lo estoy mostrando actualmente, funciona, envía el valor lo recibo y obtengo el resultado que espero, el detalle es que quiero quitar el botón de submit para poder dar click en la imagen nada más y que se envíe el formulario, pero al parecer no envía el valor.

Comment: @MauEspaña  ok, le hice update a la respuesta. Trata eso.